# Metaprogramming language

Tags: programming-languages

Is there any programming language, by which I can write a code that during run time automatically generates so many other codes and furthermore those codes will be run in parallel?

Comment: Any general programming language should give you that mechanism via generics or meta programming. cf. `fork()` in C/stdlib. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I am going to develop an algorithm for solution of a set of partial differential equation for 1000 set of boundary conditions. Given it takes long time to run 1000 times a traditional algorithm and input aforesaid set of the boundary conditions for 1000 times, I need an algorithm that automatically input the boundary conditions and run 1000 computations in parallel simultanously

Comment: if each instance just takes different inputs but works on the same logic you can do it via multi threading/multi processing techniques. you do not need meta programming. also, you may want to try stackexchange as its a better forum for programming related questions

Comment: "run 1000 computations in parallel simultanously": do you own a supercomputer ?